# Unable to send data of multiple queries to ajax call in django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, django-views

And I want to pass two data queries result named `mydata` and `yourdata`, the problem is when I send only `mydata` or `yourdata` then its working fine but when I send in context variable its not working at all, I am new in `django` so any kind of help would be appreciated thanks.

```
@csrf_exempt
def snippetrequests(request):
    import json
    mydata=changerequest.objects.filter(owner_id=request.user.id)
    yourdata=changerequest.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
    mydata=serializers.serialize('json',mydata)
    yourdata=serializers.serialize('json',yourdata)
    if request.method == 'GET':
       context = {
          'mydata':mydata ,
          'yourdata':yourdata
               }
    return HttpResponse(context, content_type="application/json" )
```

And I am getting Data from it using AJAX like this

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/snippetrequests/',
    type: 'GET',
    data={},
    success: function(data) {
        // alert(data);
         alert(data)
        console.log(data)
        var div1 = document.getElementById('snippet');   
    },
    failure: function(data) { 
        alert('Got an error dude');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return context with the help of json.dumps(), like

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type="application/json" )
```

json.dumps basically converts your context dictionary to a string.

If you see the HttpResponse class code it basically takes a string as content, content=b'' is taken as the default argument, where b meaning bytes, your content is then converted to bytestring and joined with b'' and set.

Hence you need to use json.dumps(content).

OR you can try JsonResponse which extends HttpResponse class, with default Content-Type header as application/json

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

return JsonResponse(context)
```

Comment: its converting my both query objects into string :(

Comment: Your query objects will get converted to a string, serialization is what is used to convert data in json objects which further to string for the response.

Comment: thanks . I did json parse on javascript side then working fine now

Answer (score 1):

You've serialized the model data, but not your direct response; it is still in dictionary format. As such, `HTTPResponse` is likely just returning a string that kinda-sorta looks like JSON, instead of actual JSON.

Use `json.dumps` as part of your `return` statement.

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(context), content_type="application/json")
```

Or better yet, if you're using Django 1.7+, use the `JsonResponse` object:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

. . .

return JsonResponse(context)
```

Comment: its converting my both query objects into string :(